Spark UDF does not compute the final value on DataFrame, but it does on a test DataFrame
I have a dataframe that is a list of Delta tables in the hive_metastore.
For each table, I want to fetch the Delta Log to extract some information. I can do this by collecting the DataFrame in an Array and processing each row separately (sequentially or in parallel), but I am trying to test if using UDFs could speed up all or some parts.
The UDF:
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val udfGetDeltaLog = udf(
  (catalog: String, database: String, table: String) => {
    val deltaLog = try {
      Some(DeltaLog.forTable(spark, TableIdentifier(table, Some(database), Some(catalog))))
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => None
    }

    deltaLog match {
      case Some(log) => log.logPath.toString
      case None => null
    }
  }
)

spark.udf.register("udfGetDeltaLog", udfGetDeltaLog)

The original DataFrame with schema and few rows (I edited the name of the tables for compliancy reasons):
inputTables.printSchema

root
 |-- catalog_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- database_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_name: string (nullable = true)

inputTables.limit(3).show(false)

+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
|catalog_name  |database_name|table_name                                 |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
|hive_metastore|adw_poc      |table1                                     |
|hive_metastore|alfam        |table2                                     |
|hive_metastore|alfam        |table3                                     |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+

The test DataFrame I created:
val df = Seq(
  ("hive_metastore", "adw_poc", "table1"), 
  ("hive_metastore", "alfam", "table2"), 
  ("hive_metastore", "alfam", "table3")
).toDF("catalog_name", "database_name", "table_name")

df.printSchema

root
 |-- catalog_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- database_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table_name: string (nullable = true)


When I use the UDF with the test DataFrame, I get:
df
  .withColumn("dl", udfGetDeltaLog($"catalog_name", $"database_name", $"table_name"))
  .show(false)

+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|dl                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/adw_poc.db/table1/_delta_log       |
|dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/alfam.db/table2/_delta_log         |
|dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/alfam.db/table3/_delta_log         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+

But when I use the UDF on the original DataFrame, I get all null values
+----+
|dl  |
+----+
|null|
|null|
|null|
+----+

Do you know why this is happening?
Cheers

If you look at the plan for your test dataset you'll see it's a LocalRelation, these behave differently than other plans.  As the name indicates it runs local to the driver and on Databricks 15.x this will cause compilation to be disabled.
The key reason for the actual behavior is likely due to your use of the spark variable:
val deltaLog = try {
      Some(DeltaLog.forTable(spark, TableIdentifier(table, Some(database), Some(catalog))))
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => None
    }

this will be null on executors.  This typically would result in an NPE, but as you are catching Throwable you end up with a None which you then map to the null you see in your output dataset.
You cannot use SparkSession or SQLContext etc. on executors.

Damn, thanks for pointing it out, it looks so silly now! So my only strategies to get the Delta Log for each table is to iterate through each row, extract the string with the full table name and fetch the log, right?

unless you have millions of tables I'd suggest collecting them to a Seq and using Seq.map, if you really need a dataset you can always create one from the resulting Seq

Yes, that is what I originally did, i.e. collecting all the tables (~130K) into a sequence and parallelly processing the elements (.par.map(etc..)). Thanks for the tips
